# How can i focus(using jquery) the Kendo Combo box in dynamically generated table(using foreach)?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a dynamically created table . i filled the data using foreach. And i need to focus the Kendo combobox at initial...

```
 <tbody id="commisionDataTable">
                            <!-- ko foreach:CommissionSplits -->
                            <tr>
                                <td data-bind="text:$index()+1"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="stfname1" data-bind="kendoComboBox: { dataTextField: 'Name', dataValueField: 'ResID', data: $root.AllStaffList, value: ResourceID ,spin:onCommisionResChange,change:onCommisionResChange,enabled:true}"
                                        style="width: 99%" />
                                </td></tr></tbody>
```

I tried this code but it's not working.

```
  var kendocombobox = $("#stfname1").data("kendoComboBox");
    kendocombobox.focus();
```

Comment: you need to focus on this as it is created or on some action

Comment: As i see it: `var kendocombobox = $("#stfname1");` then focus method should work. But as IDs must be unique, looks like your loop generate invalid HTML markup

Comment: I wrote that code on Button event.. But it did not focus

Answer (score 1):

You'll end up with multiple inputs with the same id using your code. I'd suggest removing the id completely; instead you can use a CSS class, e.g. `combo` and select as

```
var row = $("#commisionDataTable").find("tr").eq(0); 
var comboBox = $(row).find("input.combo").eq(0).data("kendoComboBox");
// comboBox.input is the input generated by the widget
$(comboBox.input).focus(); // or, equivalent: comboBox.focus()
```

Simply focusing the input you created won't work since it is hidden by the widget.

You also need to make sure this code is running after knockout has finished updating the DOM - you can use the [`afterRender`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) callback for that. (although I'm not familiar enough with knockout to say whether that is the best solution)